# Create different types of pallets with an ID which have different colors and insert them with a source block

Tags: anylogic

After I asked yesterday I try to make it clearer. I would like to create different pallet types (ID) which should have a different color. My agent Pallet has different colors and the parameter id. So I created the dbase pallets_db with the different ids (every id should have a different color). Now I would like to insert the different pallet types to different dates into my source block. For that task I have another dbase called arrivaltime where I have the pallet type ID, the dates and the number of pallets I would like to insert with source. The pallet type ID and the dbase pallets_db are connected with the foreign key. 
What should I do next? I dont know how my IDs get the different colors and how I get it into the source block after it. 
So Color blue = id 1 
For example it should be: At 6 am 30 blue (id=1) pallets will be insert.
Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

First this is the way you create your source:

[image: source]

so agents per arrival:

```
(int) selectFrom(db_table)
    .where(db_table.date.eq(self.arrivalDate()))
    .firstResult(db_table.amount)
```

then to get the id of your agent, on the "on at exit" action you do

```
agent.id=(int) selectFrom(db_table)
    .where(db_table.date.eq(date()))
    .firstResult(db_table.id));
```

This doesn't automatically create a color for your pallets, but at least you will have all your pallets with the correct ID

Comment: thank you. and how can I get the different colors for my ids?

Comment: is it a 3D object? if it is, check the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903858/how-can-we-change-3d-animation-object-agents-representation-color-based-on-sta/61908106#61908106 if it's not, you can generally define the color easily

Comment: It‘s both. I have 2d and 3d. So define the color easily means to have a color block and call it like the ID number?

Comment: you need to transform your id into an actual color... you need basically a function that returns a color for each id, or maybe add the RGB color code to your database for each id... so not THAT easily